# text overflow using ellipsis property issue

Tags: jquery, html

i added the ellipsis property but in order to see this property one has to move to the begin of the text box.

So my requirement is to show the text from the beginning once focus is lost for that text box.

Comment: show the code and issue please! :)

Comment: maybe put the code on http://jsfiddle.net/ then we can help

Comment: eg: my input text box maxlength is 1000. and after enter 10 characters the overflow happens. like i entered ABCDXVGFDTGSG. I want to show it from the beginning like ABCD... on focus lose of the same.